# Nearly identical reducers for different APIs

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm using ngrx as a state container for an Angular2 app. Right now, I have three API calls that retrieve a list of ads, a list of departments, and details for an individual department. You can only *retrieve* this information. You will never be able to update or otherwise manipulate it in the app. My application state looks like:

```
{
  ads: Ad[],
  departments: Department[],
  selectedDepartment: Department,
}
```

This works great, and I can get slices of these in my components with `this.store.select('ads')`, etc. Everything is working fine.

One issue I'm running into is that I have a lot of very similar looking 
and simple boilerplate ... particularly for the reducers. Example:

```
export const departmentsReducer = (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case LOAD_DEPARTMENTS:
      return state;

    case LOAD_DEPARTMENTS_COMPLETE:
      return payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I have `LOAD_x` which uses [ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects) to trigger loading data from the API through my service. Then `LOAD_x_COMPLETE` which takes that data returned from the API and updates the state container.

Is there any way to reduce the amount of boilerplate when creating these reducers since they all function in more or less the same way? The only real difference is the API they end up using.

Comment: You could create a factory that creates reducers, I suppose, but I don't think it'd save you as much boilerplate as you'd like

Answer (score -1):

Here's a recommendation from the official redux docs:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html#generating-reducers

They recommend making a createReducer function like so:

```
function createReducer(initialState, handlers) {
  return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
      return handlers[action.type](state, action)
    } else {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can create the reducer:

```
 export const todos = createReducer([], {
   [ActionTypes.ADD_TODO](state, action) {
     let text = action.text.trim()
     return [...state, text]
   }
 })
```